# O que é esse __set_state que aparece no var_export?

Tags: php

O `var_export` serve para exportar os dados de um determinado valor como um código php válido.

Porém, quando eu utilizo ele em um objeto da classe `stdClass`, ele me retorna o seguinte código:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
                 'one' => 1,
                 'two' => 1,
))
```

Porém, se eu tentar fazer:

```
stdClass::__set_state(['one' => 1]);
```

Ele me retorna

> Call to undefined method stdClass::__set_state()

E, de fato, ele não existe lá.

```
  var_dump(method_exists($object, '__set_state')); // false
```

De onde é que apareceu esse tal de `__set_state`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`__set_state()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.set-state) é uma função do grupo de métodos mágicos utilizados pelo PHP em classes.

Básicamente qualquer função que comece por `__` é uma função mágica.

> This static method is called for classes exported by [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) since PHP 5.1.0.
>
> The only parameter of this method is an array containing exported properties in the form `array('property' => value, ...)`.

Que traduzido:

> Este método estático é chamado para classes exportadas pela função [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) a partir do PHP 5.1.0.
>
> O único parâmetro para esse método é uma matriz contendo propriedades exportadas no formato `array('property' => value, ...)`.

O seu correto uso pode ser observado na documentação:

```
class A
{
    public $var1;
    public $var2;

    public static function __set_state($an_array)
    {
        $obj = new A;
        $obj->var1 = $an_array['var1'];
        $obj->var2 = $an_array['var2'];
        return $obj;
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->var1 = 5;
$a->var2 = 'foo';
```

Onde podemos executar a atribuição do resultado da função [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) no objeto `$a` para o objeto `$b`:

```
eval('$b = ' . var_export($a, true) . ';');

// Resultado do eval():
$b = A::__set_state(array(
    'var1' => 5,
    'var2' => 'foo',
));
```

E assim obter como saída:

```
var_dump($b);

// Saída:
object(A)#2 (2) {
   ["var1"]=>
    int(5)
    ["var2"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
}
```

Comment: Ou seja, `var_export` só serve para ser utilizado em objetos se os mesmos implementarem `__set_state`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters É o meu entendimento sim. Mas como não uso muito, poderá existir alguma outra aplicação prática para essa "magia".